# Libre Office calculator characters

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, special-characters

I'm translating a user manual([this](https://www.techadv.com.au/literature/ohaus/userguides/ohaus-scout-sjx-user-guide.pdf)) of Digital Scales. I need to write certain words as they appear on the digital screen of the scale. In the [official pdf](https://www.techadv.com.au/literature/ohaus/userguides/ohaus-scout-sjx-user-guide.pdf) they have managed somehow (check characters at page EN6) but when I convert it to .odt file, the words get replaced with common letters. e.g. "[mMeNU]" (originally it was with "digital calculator" characters).[image: difference between words]

Answer (score 0):

That's a special font. An Internet search for *[digital calculator fonts](https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+calculator+fonts)* will provide many results. Pick and choose.

Comment: will do. thx a lot beforehand